# Vue: How to change a value of state and use it in other page and change page structure at starting by it?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In this project, we can login from `login.vue` by clicking `login` button and if it is success then we can see `Lnb.vue` in `dashboard.vue`

I thought if i code like this then `pageSso` will be `1` when I check the checkbox in `login.vue` in `Lnb.vue` then it will not show only "Account" menu.
When I used `console.log(pageSso)` at mounted cycle it showed `pageSso` was `0`. What would be the problem?

**store/store.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
    pageSso: 0,
})
export const getters = {
    pageSso: (state) => state.pageSso,
}

export const mutations = {
    setPageSso(state, data) {
        console.log('mutations setPageSso data', data)
        state.pageSso = data
    }
}

export const actions = {
    setPageSso({
        commit
    }, data) {
        console.log('actions setPageSso data', data)
        commit('setPageSso', data)
    },

}
```

**pages/login.vue**

```html
<template>
<input
  class="checkbox_sso"
  type="checkbox"
  v-model="sso"
  true-value="1"
  false-value="0" >SSO checkbox
  <button class="point" @click="submit">login</button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        sso: '',
      }
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {
      submit() {
        this.$store.dispatch('store/setPageSso', this.sso)
        //this.$store.dispatch('store/login', data)
      },
</script>
```

**pages/dashboard.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="base flex">
        <Lnb />
        <div class="main">
            <Gnb />
            <nuxt-child />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Lnb from '@/components/Lnb'
    import Gnb from '@/components/Gnb'
    export default {
        components: {
            Lnb,
            Gnb
        },
        mounted() {},
    }
</script>
```

**components/Lnb.vue**

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <li :class="{ active: navbarState == 7 ? true : false }">
      <a href="/dashboard/settings">
        <img src="../assets/images/ico_settings.svg" alt="icon" /> Settings
      </a>
    </li>
    <li v-show="pageSso != 1" :class="{ active: navbarState == 8 ? true : false }">
      <a href="/dashboard/user">
        <img src="../assets/images/ico_user.svg" alt="icon" />
        Account
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
  import {
    mapState
  } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState('store', {
        // navbarState: (state) => state.navbarState,

        pageSso: (state) => state.pageSso,
      }),
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('pageSso ->', this.pageSso);
    },
    methods: {

    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log(pageSso)` logs `0` because the mounted hook of Lnb.vue happens once, and it happens when the component is inserted into the DOM.

You insert Lnb into the DOM unconditionally in this line of dashboard.vue:

```
<Lnb />
```

and this is roughly when it's mounted hook is triggered.

Your `pageSso` seems to be changed only after you triggered the `submit()` method, which — I guess — happens way later, when you submit the login form.

Your Lnb.vue currently is always mounted. If you don't want to show it until pageSso is equal to 1, add a v-if on it in dashboard.vue like this:

```
<Lnb v-if="pageSso === 1" />
```

You currently don't have pageSso variable in dashboard.vue, you must take it from the store.

**N.B.:** Mind the difference between `v-show` and `v-if` directives: `v-show` only hides the component with `display: none;` while `v-if` actually removes or inserts the component from/to the DOM. With `v-show`, the component gets mounted even if you don't see it. With `v-if`, the component's mounted hook will fire each time the condition evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I changed my question a little now. I want to change just `<li>Account</li>` by the `sso`(in `login.vue`) => `pageSso`(in `store.js' and `Lnb.vue`) value.

Comment: And I thought that `pageSso` will be saved at `submit` in `login.vue` and we can use the saved value anywhere in the project. Maybe this is not true

Comment: Yes, pageSso in the store is defined when you defined it, and it is available across the project. In your current setup, you define pageSso as 0 until changed by the action dispatched in submit method. The way you have it now, you always see the <li>Account</li> until pageSso changes to 1 in the store. I hope you understand the console.log you have in your Lnb.vue/mounted will run only once and when it runs, it will be zero yet because you haven't yet called submit at that moment.

Comment: If you want to log pageSso changes into console, you have to either move the console.log into your computed, or use a watch. You may also use the Vuex tab in the Vue developer toolbar instead of logging to the console.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed out of that submit button. Now I wrote the source to here too and it's from original source what didn't work. I called submit when I clicked the button, but it didn't change. Anyway thank you for telling me the Vuex tab way I'll try use it